# trying to set an input parameter for an angular2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that I am trying to pass an @Input parameter and printing the variable. The input parameter is always undefined.

In index.html I have..

```
    <body>
<flowsheet [sides]="6">Loading...</flowsheet>
```

in the component file, I have

```
@Component({
    providers: [],
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'flowsheet',
    templateUrl: './flowsheet.component.html'
})


export class FlowsheetComponent {
    @Input() sides: Number;

   ngOnInit() {
      console.log(' ***** ' + this.sides + ' *******');
   }
}
```

flowsheet.component.html has

```
<div>
<ag-grid-ng2 id="flowsheet"
        #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100px;box-sizing: border-box;" class="ag-fresh"
             [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
             [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
             [rowData]="rowData"

>
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

Any thoughts on what the error is?

Comment: what is the console log?

Comment: '****undefined****